# Is there a way to prevent warnings from printing in pdf or html file?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am working with JupyterLab and while working with square roots or complex values, python gives `RuntimeWarning` or `ComplexWarning`. Is there a way to prevent these warning from showing up when saving the file into a pdf or html?

Comment: `python -W ignore foo.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top your script:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

[Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)